# Carregar GridView com dados de variável

Tags: c#, asp.net, variáveis, gridview

Tenho 3 variáveis cujos valores são alterados dentro de um laço `for`. O que estou tentando fazer é pegar esses valores que são obtidos nas variáveis e carrega-los em um GridView. Eis o que eu tentei fazer, sem sucesso:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    converteMacroHexadecimal(EntidadeMacro.Texto);
    int numCoordenadas = getNumeroDeCoordenadas();

    var b = EntidadeMacro.Texto;

    TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(HexToInt(EntidadeMacro.Texto));

    string latitude = "";
    string longitude = "";
    string velocidade = "";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(latitude, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add(longitude, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add(velocidade, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

    for (int i = 1; i <= numCoordenadas; i++)
    {
        latitude = getLatitude(i);
        longitude = getLongitude(i);
        velocidade = getVelocidade(i);

        dt.Rows.Add(new String[] { latitude.ToString(),"Latitude" });
    }

    GridViewPontosTroca.DataSource = dt;
    GridViewPontosTroca.DataBind();

    //GridViewPontosTroca.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = getLatitude(0);
    //GridViewPontosTroca.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text = getLongitude(1);
    //GridViewPontosTroca.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text = getVelocidade(2);
    TextBox1.Text = macro;
    //   t.Text = Convert.ToString(numCoordenadas);
    var a = Convert.ToString(ParametroDeAproximacaoMaxima());
    TextBoxAproximacaoMaxima.Text = Convert.ToString(ParametroDeAproximacaoMaxima());
}
```

Comment: O que acontece? qual o problema? tente debugar e ver onde que esta o problema...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta criando um datatable com colunas de nome = "":

Como deve ser corretamente:

```
int numCoordenadas = getNumeroDeCoordenadas();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("latitude", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("longitude", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("velocidade", typeof(string));

for (int i = 1; i <= numCoordenadas; i++)
{
    var latitude = getLatitude(i).ToString(); //verifica se esta retornando um valor correto!
    var longitude = getLongitude(i).ToString(); //verifica se esta retornando um valor correto!
    var velocidade = getVelocidade(i).ToString();//verifica se esta retornando um valor correto!
    dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {latitude, longitude, velocidade});
}

GridViewPontosTroca.DataSource = dt;
```